# AWS Athena partition projection - use integer or date for yyyymmdd

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a parquet data lake on S3, structured as below:

```
s3://bucket/deviceid/table_x/20230102/xyz.parquet
```

Here, I am using the partition structure `yyyymmdd`.

When setting up my table, I wish to add 'partition projection' to avoid having to use a Glue crawler (or similar) to update my table when new partitions are added.

I am currently using settings as below, where `date` is my partition column (`int`).

[image]

My question is this:

Would I be better off defining my partition projection as a `date` type instead of an `int` type? And then specifying the format as `yyyymmdd`. The reason I consider this is mainly that I'm concerned regarding the AWS Docs stating that 'partition projection gaps' can cause performance issues. If I'm using an integer range and I query the period 20100101 to 20110101, I am of course having a range of 1000 integers - but in reality only 365 days. It is unclear to me how Athena/Glue will realize that my partition projection is in fact to be interpreted as a date if I user integer - and whether it will thus correctly disregard 'non-valid' date integers such as 20102060 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by instead using a sub folder structure `yyyy/mm/dd` and using date style partition projection as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194112/sql-query-data-from-a-time-period-with-year-month-day-partitions).